# Windows.Devices.Custom.IOControlCode in Windows 10 Universal

Tags: c#, driver, windows-10, win-universal-app

Can I use Windows.Devices.Custom.IOControlCode in Windows 10 Universal Apps? I am trying to use a custom driver, and this is what Microsoft said to use for Windows 8.1 apps. Anyone know a work around?

When I try to use Windows.Devices.Custom.IOControlCode in my Windows 10 Universal App I get the error:

> Error CS1069  The type name 'IOControlCode' could not be found in the
>   namespace 'Windows.Devices.Custom'. This type has been forwarded to
>   assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a
>   reference to that assembly

I don't understand what assembly it is saying to add? Windows Runtime? Where is that located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Reference -> Universal Windows-> Extensions-> Microsoft Desktop Extension SDK for Universal App Platform.